# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object on ExecuteScalar DateTime

Tags: c#, executescalar

Getting operation in not valid error when doing ExecuteScalar() to return a date.    No errors on compile and I'm not sure why this isn't working - message is not helping me understand.  Any thoughts?

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(----------)
 {
     using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
     {
         con.Open();
         cmd.CommandText = "select end_date from calendar where :today >= begin_date and :today <= end_date";
         DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
         cmd.Parameters.Add(":today", OracleDbType.Date).Value = today;
         try
         {                         
             DateTime ppEndDate = (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you check if ex.InnerException is not null? If not what is the error message of the InnerException?

Comment: I would expect inner exception as well. You might also inspect the status of con before ExecuteScalar (con.State)

Comment: Is `:today` a valid parameter name? I usually tend to use `@today` in such situations

Comment: ex.Message = "Operation is not valid due to current state of the object.

Comment: Please bear with me as I am very new at C# and debugging in general. 
 To answer your questions:   
ex.Message = "Operation is not valid due to current state of the object., the con is working fine
The today variable is returning the current date, but I don't see a way to validate the parameter.  
This is querying an Oracle database.  I was previously using @ which works for SQL, but I was told 
by a colleague to use : for Oracle parameters.

Comment: ppEndDate is returning null.  When I run a similar query on the database using Toad, 
I get the appropriate date returned 4/19/2017 
(i.e., select end_date
from calendar
where sysdate >= begin_date 
and sysdate <= end_date)